# nodejs_express_Path of Static Files(bower_components) Changed due to 'GET requests to the /user/:id path'

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

Problem: My problem is that the route conversion will result in the path of static files changed. Those are dependence files store in 'bower_components'.

Those are dependence files work well on the index page. Others could not work due to the static files path changed.In other words, bootstrap could not work on 'localhost:3000/product/id',but well on 'localhost:3000'.

What I did: I thought this error result from middleware, thus, I was trying to use 'app.use()'  instead of 'app.get()' . unfortunately, more error came out.

[click it: The image explain the wrong path when I use app.get()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCuiR.png)

My directory system looks like this:

```
shop
  -/bower_components
      -/bootstrap
      -/jquery
  -/views
      -/includes
         -head.jade
         -header.jade
      -/pages
         -admin.jade
         -detail.jade
         -index.jade
         -list.jade
      -layout.jade
  -app.js
```

My app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var serveStatic = require('serve-static');
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'./views/pages'));
app.set('view engine','jade');
app.use('/bower_components',express.static(path.join(__dirname,'bower_components/')));
app.listen(port);
console.log('shop is start on port'+ port);
//index.page
app.get('/',function(req,res){
   res.render('index',{
       title: 'Home',
       productes:[{
         title:'SWISSE',
          _id:1,
        poster:'http://p5.img.ymatou.com/upload/productdes/baee6566fd7545ef8fb0efd94af97a8d.jpg',
    },
    {
        title:'SWISSE',
        _id:3,
        poster:'http://p5.img.ymatou.com/upload/productdes/baee6566fd7545ef8fb0efd94af97a8d.jpg',
    },
    {
        title:'SWISSE',
        _id:2,
        poster:'http://p5.img.ymatou.com/upload/productdes/baee6566fd7545ef8fb0efd94af97a8d.jpg',
    }]
    })
});

//detail.page
app.use('/product/:id',function(req,res){
res.render('detail',{
    title: 'Detail',
    product: {
        title:'swiss',
        poster:'http://www.pharmacyonline.com.au/media/catalog/product/cache/6/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/7/379352.jpg',
        price:'110',
        place:'nz',
        description:'whatever',
    }
})});
```

My head looks like this:

```
link(href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')

script(src='bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')

script(src='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

My layout is like this:

```
doctype
  html
   head
      meta(charset='utf-8')
      title #{title}
      include ./includes/head
   body
     include ./includes/header
   block content
```

My detail page is like this:

```
extends ../layout

block content
.container
  .row
    .col-xs-12.col-md-7
      img(src='#{product.poster}',alt='#{product.title}',width='720',height='600',align='middle')
    .col-xs-12.col-md-5
      dl.dl-horizontal
        dt  Name
        dd #{product.title}
        dt  Price
        dd #{product.price}
        dt  Production place
        dd #{product.place}
        dt  Description
        dd #{product.description}
```

Comment: If you downvote, please tell me why. So that your downvote can help me to avoid asking a stupid question next time. Please! At least let me know why!But,  It's okay if you think it is the silly question for the downvote. But for me, the answer to this issue is critical for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change the path of your js/css files.

```
link(href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')

script(src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js')

script(src='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js')
```

it is because you use a relative path.